# Bazel select condition for a specific GCC major-version

Tags: bazel

We have to pass a special `linkopts` flag to `cc_library` rules that use `<filesystem>`, specifically for the GCC version that ships with Debian 10 (gcc 8.3).

I don't want to make developers pass a `--config=old_gcc` or similar at the top level.

I was hoping an incantation kind of like this would work:

```
    linkopts = select({
       "@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:gcc": ["-lstdc++fs"],
       "//conditions:default": [],
    }),
```

But a) gcc is not a configurable attribute that `select()` can use and b) we more specifically should test the version number is 8 (we'll only support 8 or above).

How do I extract a `is_gcc8`-like config_setting I can select on like this for targets using `<filesystem>`? TIA!

Comment: I suspect you're asking, which `config_setting` label can I choose configurable attribute based on version of `gcc` you got form automatic toolchain resolution. If so, you cannot. The automatic toolchain resolution doesn't even ask for version of `gcc` used, let alone expose it as `config_setting`. Define different/specific toolchains would be both "correct" and could provide something to tap into; The cheap (on initial one time effort) and dirty option might be to have one magical toolchain that checks and decides in a wrapper calling `gcc`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to change to using a manual CROSSTOOL setup instead of relying on the automatic crosstool setup (documentation [here](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/0.22.0/crosstool-reference.html)). This would allow you to specify a set of linker flags to apply when compiling with a certain combination of `--cpu` and `--compiler`.